# How to view a password saved PDF File

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api

I want to open the following PDF-File: http://www.bertbrechtgymnasium.de/vertretungsplan/schueler_heute.pdf , but everytime I have tried to open it through Google Drive. This error appears- 
"Sorry, we couldn't find the File you requested". Is there any other possibility to view this PDF File?

**At the time i use the following code:**

```
Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PDF_READER_PREFIX + 
"http://www.bertbrechtgymnasium.de/vertretungsplan/schueler_heute.pdf" )
,HTML_MIME_TYPE );
startActivity( i );
```

**My Problem:**

The Problem is that the PDF File is saved with a Username and Password.
I know Username and Password but there appears no window or something to sign in.

Thanks for your help.